# Spring Resttemplate unexpected field "session" in the post data

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

```
{
    "platform": "iOS",
    "device": {
        "os_name": "iPhone OS",
        "manufacturer": "Apple",
        "type": "iPhone3",
        "version": "1",
        "os_version": "5.1.1"
    },
    "app_version": "1.0",
    "device_id": "",
    "app_key": "1234567890",
    "developer_key": "",
    "app_name": "test",
        "session": { // here
        "platform": "iOS",
        "device": {
            "os_name": "iPhone OS",
            "manufacturer": "Apple",
            "type": "iPhone3",
            "version": "1",
            "os_version": "5.1.1"
        },
        "app_version": "1.0",
        "device_id": "",
        "app_key": "1234567890",
        "developer_key": "",
        "app_name": "test"
    }
}
```

This is the data generated by MappingJacksonConverter but I don't know how to disable the "session" field containing the whole recursive data.

```
HttpEntity<OlSession> sessionEntity = new HttpEntity<OlSession>(new OlSession());

ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:3000/test/abcd", sessionEntity, String.class);
```

This is the code to post the above data. Is there any part that I need to add to disable the "session" field?

Comment: What is OlSession? did you make the pojo?

Comment: Yep that is pojo class containing all the data from "platform" field to "app_name"field

Answer (score 0):

There are two simple solution.

1) Use jackson annotation to ignore that property.

But in this way, session in OlSession property will not be serialized everywhere.

```
@JsonIgnore
Object getSession() {
  return session
}
```

Take a look this doc [JacksonAnnotation](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonAnnotations)

2) Just set null before you send.

Comment: `public class OlSession {

 private String platform = "iOS";

 private OlSessionDevice device = new OlSessionDevice();
 
 private String app_version = "1.0";
 private String device_id = "";
 private String app_key = "2aa950bc95a950dd21e25e67760f5e96";
 private String developer_key = "";
 private String app_name = "Daily Deals For Me";
........ setter and getter
}`
As you can see there is no session field, how can I set the JsonIgnore annotation?

Can you specify the second method more in detail? It would be nice if you provide some example code.

Thank you

Comment: It is the weird thing to me where the session is coming from though there is no session field. I guess the Jackson library automatically attach the session field at the end of the fields. Can you give some information as to this, if you have some experience in this. Thank you

Comment: what about getters/setters? Are you sure there is no method like 'getSession' in OlSession?

Comment: Yep I am pretty sure there is no method like getSession in OlSession class.

Comment: `public String getPlatform() {
 return platform;
}

public void setPlatform(String platform) {
 this.platform = platform;
}`
For each fields, These two set/get method are declared.

Comment: So wired... jackson finds every getter in pojo by reflection, so getSession method or something sort of that must be there.... wellll

Comment: Can you tell me in detail about the second method then?